# MSBuild ignores the desired configuration

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build a Visual Studio 2019 solution from command line (though a PowerShell script), I need to have 2 builds - one for 64-bit and one for 32-bit though the script.

From Configuration Manager I have added x86 and x64 platforms to the Platform:
[image]

And in the project properties I have set up the Platform target accordingly:
[image]

I'm using the following command lines to build with MSBuild:

```
& $msbuildPath ../MyApp.Desktop.sln -t:Rebuild -p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86
```

```
& $msbuildPath ../MyApp.Desktop.sln -t:Rebuild -p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

But it seems to ignore the `/p:Platform` because it does not matter if I state `x86` or `x64` it always builds the "Active" platform set in Configuration Manager. But, if I put in platform an invalid value (for instance x123) the build would fail because that does not exist.

How can I make MSBuild actually build with the stated `/p:Platform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your sln file, you should change the **solution platform** rather than the **project platform**.

Please try the following steps:

**1)** first, delete every project platform and do a clean for your project.And only retain the platform `Any CPU`.

[image]

**2)** add the new `x64` and `x86` platform for the **solution platform**

[image]

**3)** close VS Instance, delete the `bin` and `obj` folder of every project

then run your powershell with `/p:Platform=x64 or x86`. And it works well in my side. And it can return `x86` or `x64` output files without any problems.

[image]