# Visual Studio 2019 configuration the complied .dll assembly does not exist

Tags: c#, dll, configuration, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging

I'm running a project in `Visual Studio 2019`, where I'm using the `CefSharp` package, which requires me to set **Debug/Release** configuration modes as **x64**.

When I run my project, I get an error that it *Failed to Initialize* because:

> the assemby "C:\myProject\Work\Code\myProject..\myProject.dll" does
> not exist.

My project folder is:

```
C:\myProject\Work\Code\myProject\myProject
```

I've set the mode to **Debug** and **x64**, with the `Output path` as `x64\`, meaning that it is directed to:

```
C:\myProject\Work\Code\myProject\myProject\x64
```

When I check the folder contents, for both of the folder locations mentioned above, they both contain a "myProject.dll" file.

but the error is still there.. even when I place the full path in the `Output path`, and not just `x64\`, it still doesn't work.

I'm wondering what could be wrong because even if the .dll is not 'correct', it should still find it.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I've tried the solution suggested in the ***first answer***. I've checked the `.csproj` file, I've deleted the `bin/obj/.vs` folders and tried what is in the link suggested.

When I restart VS it is on `AnyCPU` by default. If I build it as such, it compiles without error, but when I run the application it fails and gives the error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf,
> Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'
> or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If instead of building and running as `AnyCPU` I try to switch to `x64`, then I get a compile error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'BIMbase.csproj'.
> Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
> of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'
> Platform='x64'.  This error may also appear if some other project is
> trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this
> project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the
> referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent
> Configuration or Platform.

**The .csproj as requested:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{8F2295E7-314F-47A7-992C-6756624BF6F6}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>BIMbase</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>BIMbase</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Latest|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Latest\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Latest|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Latest\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CefSharp, Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Users\yafim\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\84.4.10\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core, Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Users\yafim\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\84.4.10\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CefSharp.Core, Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Users\yafim\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\84.4.10\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CsvHelper, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\CsvHelper.15.0.4\lib\net47\CsvHelper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FireSharp, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\FireSharp.2.0.4\lib\portable-net45+sl5+wp8+win8\FireSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.1.1.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.168.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SkiaSharp, Version=1.59.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SkiaSharp.1.59.1\lib\net45\SkiaSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.28\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.28\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.4.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.4.0.0.0\lib\net40-Client\System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="UIAutomationProvider" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
    <Reference Include="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, Version=3.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.8.1\lib\net40\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Browser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Command.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CurrentStateSelection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CurrentState.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DataGraphicsDisplay.cs" />
    <Compile Include="DataGraphicsForm.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="DataGraphicsForm.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DataGraphicsForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GraphPane.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>GraphPane.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Main.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\HistoryDateSortItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\HistoryResult.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\MatchEntry.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\MaterialsCO2.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UnknownMaterial.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Request.cs" />
    <Compile Include="RequestHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SelectionTakeoffCreation.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MaterialTakeoffCreation.cs" />
    <Compile Include="NamePair.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Services\FireBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ShowUpdate.cs" />
    <Compile Include="UserMaterialDataCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="UserMaterialForm.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="UserMaterialForm.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UserMaterialForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="DataGraphicsForm.resx">
      <DependentUpon>DataGraphicsForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="UserMaterialForm.resx">
      <DependentUpon>UserMaterialForm.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="app.manifest" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\DataSources\DataGraphicsForm.datasource" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Mapping 1.csv">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Mapping 2.csv">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\BIMbase_logo_16x16.png" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\BIMbase_logo_32x32.png" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\BIMbase_piechart_16x16.png" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\BIMbase_piechart_32x32.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="GraphPane.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\SkiaSharp.1.59.1\build\net45\SkiaSharp.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.1.59.1\build\net45\SkiaSharp.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\SkiaSharp.1.59.1\build\net45\SkiaSharp.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\SkiaSharp.1.59.1\build\net45\SkiaSharp.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureBclBuildImported" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(BclBuildImported)' == ''">
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2001" />
    <Error Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2002" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\CefSharp.Wpf.84.4.10\build\CefSharp.Wpf.targets')" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>x64\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So I believe that there might be an issue with the `CefSharp` package, but I don't know how or if it will help to "restore" it, it seems to compile fine in AnyCPU, but in the x64 where it should actually run correctly, it doesn't compile.

**EDIT:**

Hi, thank you for the help.
I tried **1)** and **2)** in your **Update**.
It didn't work.
Before trying **3)**, I want to add a few more notes, maybe it will help to understand the issue.

> Note: I've completely deleted any trace of CefSharp I could find
> anywhere.

When running the Webapp, it works find on a `LocalHost`.
When running the actual app with the Client code, I get the full error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.   

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace: 

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +99
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +310
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10083304
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

Besides that, when I rebuild my project I have some errors/warnings, some of which I think are related to the 1) and 2) steps you mentioned:

> 1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4" from Version
> "2.0.19.10" [C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit
> 2020\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll] to Version "3.8.0.0"
> [C:\BIMbase\Work\Code\BIMbase\packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.8.1\lib\net40\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll]
> to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2084,5):
> warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the
> same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"
> property to true in the project file. For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.

And the 2nd error above refers to the code:

false
   true

No idea why CefSharp error still exists...

Answer (score 1):

If you add **Configuration** with `x64`, you should [try the steps as this answer described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63898530/12450747).

**Suggestion**

**After that**, you should check on your `myProject.csproj` file and make sure that you have defined the right `outputpath` for x64 mode.

**Add** like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>x64\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It will make the `outputpath` of `configuration x64` to:

`C:\myProject\Work\Code\myProject\myProject\x64`

**Besides**, check on the file and ensure there are no other `configuration x64` conditions of the properties to cause conflict with it. Remember to retain only one like the above one.

===========================================

If you already did all the steps, you could try the following steps:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder `C:\myProject\Work\Code\myProject`.

also `bin` and `obj` folder under the project folder, any `x64` folders to make a clean build environment.

**2)** restart your project to rebuild again to test it.

**In addition**, if these do not work, I suggest you could share your `myProject.csproj` file with us to help us troubleshoot the issue more quickly.

=================================

**Update 1**

**Actually**, you should build and run your project under `X64` or `X86` according to `CefSharp` nuget package's requirements. And you should not build your project under **AnyCPU** because the nuget package `CefSharp.Common` needs `x64` or `x86`.

**And** you should change the platform under **Build**-->**Configuration Manager** like this:

[image]

**1) Besides**, you should define the `Debug|x64` property alongside with other **Configuration**, **Platform** definitions:

```
..............

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Latest|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Latest\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <OutputPath>x64\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
        <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="CefSharp, Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\84.4.10\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core, Version=84.4.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\84.4.10\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

..........................
```

**2)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Conosole**.

**3)** When you build your project, try to config like this under **Build**-->**Configuration Manager**.

===========================================

**Update 2**

The workaround is to [add bindredirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions).

**Below are three ways, you could try one of them:**

**Solution**

**1)** right-click on your project-->**Add**-->**New Item**-->select **Application Configuration File** file template--> and name it as `App.config`

[image]

[image]

add these on that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="CefSharp" publicKeyToken="40c4b6fc221f4138" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-84.4.10.0" newVersion="84.4.10.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblybinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**2)** or add these xml node under your `BIMbase.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**3)** If it doesn't work, you could change `packages.config` nuget management format to PackageReference nuget management format. The issue always happens on the `packages.config` while **PackageReference** does not cause that any more.

**Note**: before you do this, you should make a backup of your project.

Right-click on the `packages.config` file--> select `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference`

[image]

===============================

**Update 3**

Sorry for knowing that your project is a web prject, so you should add the above bindredirect on the `web.config` file.

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies. An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]

The error usually indicates that your dll version is not the same as the project version. It refers to the conflict between `x64` and `x86`. See [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340362/system-badimageformatexception-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-inc).

So you should check your project very carefully.

**Besides**, add this in the `Web.config` file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock" publicKeyToken="3e4669d2f30244f4" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.8.0.0" newVersion="3.8.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Add** the **step 2** node, and then run `update-package -reinstall` under **Package Manager Console**.

**Right-click** on your **Webapp** project **Properties**-->**Build**--> make sure that you have changed the `Platfrom target` to `x64`.

**and** also Check `Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Web Projects**

Close VS, delete `bin` and `obj` folder, restart your project.

**Besides**, as the [official document](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/71/NuGet/Readme.txt#L32) recommends, you should install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

**Also**, if your PC is `x64` bit and you should can use `x64` platform in your project.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried the suggestions and added info in EDIT in the original post.

Comment: Actually, you should put the debug|x64 alongside with other configuration,platform's property definitions. I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried what you suggest, but still the same error of `Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf....` persists.

Comment: One of the build warnings is `1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "CefSharp, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138" from Version "65.0.1.0" [] to Version "84.4.10.0" [C:\BIMbase\Work\Code\BIMbase\packages\CefSharp.Common.84.4.10\build\..\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.` but I can't find app.config anywhere

Comment: Hi, thanks you. Please see more documentation of error in post edit :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I removed the app.config and placed the content in `web.config`. I also reinstalled as you say and did everything you mentioned. Now instead of a break while running the app, I get the same '.dll doesn't exist' error when I start it up, like in my original issue.

Comment: I kept playing around with it. I deleted all possible files on my system related to CefSharp, and tried an earlier version of the app, but it still gets me the error page on the localhost that says `Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core' or one of its dependencies`. How is this possible..?

Comment: Did you install the [Visual Studio C++ 2015 redistributables](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#6-how-do-i-include-the-visual-studio-c-201220132015-redistributables-with-my-application)? `CefSharp` requires that. Or you  could try the [solution one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487) from this link. Or you could downgrade your nuget package CefSharp.Common to `65.0.1`. Delete `bin` and `obj` and then try again.

Comment: I have C++ 2015-2019 installed, yes. I completely removed CefSharp and any trace of it I found on my system. So I don't know how it's possible that the error still relates to it.
How is the solution one related? It seems to refer to a different issue..?

Comment: Did you try to use `PackageReference` nuget management format? Maybe you could try tp create a new project and readd your conent into the new one to test it.

Comment: It tells me my project is "not suitable for migration"...

Comment: Try to create a new project and migrate the content into the new one.

Comment: I tried.. It didn't work. Is there a best-practice way to 'migrate' into a new project?

Comment: Please try to use this document , [migrate into a  net core web project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and before you try this, please make a backup of your project. It has more convenient than net framework project. And it won't have the issue of BindingRedirects.